Gsap infinity scroll not work with Next.js 14 app router Project, Client side Component
I cant speak english very well, sorry !!!!
Under is Translation!
I am currently developing a web application using Next.js 14 app router.
Initially, I created a simple horizontally scrolling content in a client-side component, as commented out in my code. However, I discovered the GSAP library while attempting to create a more complex, infinite-looping content where the central content is highlighted.
While integrating the GSAP library, I encountered an issue where the scrolling functionality does not work.
The type of content I want to create can be seen at the following URL: [https://wsss.tistory.com/1822]
Could anyone help me understand why the scrolling is not functioning and how I can achieve the desired infinite scrolling effect with GSAP?
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
"use client";

import styles from "@/app/(beforeLogin)/(contents)/_component/PhotocardList.module.css";

import Photocard from "@/app/(beforeLogin)/(contents)/_component/Photocard"
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

import gsap from "gsap";
import {useGSAP} from "@gsap/react"
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)

export default function PhotocardList(props) {

    const { projectListData } = props;

    const [projectList, setProjectList] = useState([]);

    // const [isScrollableR, setIsScrollableR] = useState(false);
    // const [isScrollableL, setIsScrollableL] = useState(false);

    const scrollContainerRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("projectListData:", projectListData);
        setProjectList(projectListData);
    }, [projectListData])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("scrollContainerRef:", scrollContainerRef.current);
    }, []);


    useGSAP(() => {

        console.log("데이터 만들어짐 :", projectList);

        function buildSeamlessLoop(items, spacing) {
            let overlap = Math.ceil(1 / spacing);
            let startTime = items.length * spacing + 0.5;
            let loopTime = (items.length + overlap) * spacing + 1;
            let rawSequence = gsap.timeline({ paused: true });
            let seamlessLoop = gsap.timeline({
                paused: true,
                repeat: -1,
                onRepeat() {
                    this._time === this._dur && (this.tTime += this._dur - 0.01);
                }
            });
            let l = items.length + overlap * 2;
            let time = 0;
            let i, index, item;
        
            gsap.set(items, { xPercent: 500, opacity: 0, scale: 0 });
        
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                index = i % items.length;
                item = items[index];
                time = i * spacing;
                rawSequence.fromTo(item, { scale: 0, opacity: 0 }, { scale: 1, opacity: 1, zIndex: 100, duration: 0.5, yoyo: true, repeat: 1, ease: "power1.in", immediateRender: false }, time)
                    .fromTo(item, { xPercent: 400 }, { xPercent: -400, duration: 1, ease: "none", immediateRender: false }, time);
                i <= items.length && seamlessLoop.add("label" + i, time);
            }
        
            rawSequence.time(startTime);
            seamlessLoop.to(rawSequence, {
                time: loopTime,
                duration: loopTime - startTime,
                ease: "none"
            }).fromTo(rawSequence, { time: overlap * spacing + 1 }, {
                time: startTime,
                duration: startTime - (overlap * spacing + 1),
                immediateRender: false,
                ease: "none"
            });
            return seamlessLoop;
        }
        
        if (!scrollContainerRef.current) return;

        const container = scrollContainerRef.current;
        const cards = container.querySelectorAll(`.${styles.photocard}`);
        
        console.log("container:", container);
        console.log("cards:", cards);

        if (!cards.length) return;

        let iteration = 0;

        const spacing = 0.1;
        const snap = gsap.utils.snap(spacing);
        const seamlessLoop = buildSeamlessLoop(cards, spacing)
        console.log("seamlessLoop:", seamlessLoop);
        const scrub = gsap.to(seamlessLoop, {
            totalTime: 0,
            duration: 0.5,
            ease: "power3",
            paused: true
        })
        const trigger = ScrollTrigger.create({
            start: 0,
            onUpdate(self) {
                if (self.progress === 1 && self.direction > 0 && !self.wrapping) {
                    wrapForward(self);
                }
                else if (self.progress < 1e-5 && self.direction < 0 && !self.wrapping) {
                    wrapBackward(self);
                }
                else {
                    scrub.vars.totalTime = snap((iteration + self.progress) * seamlessLoop.duration)
                    scrub.invalidate().restart();
                    self.wrapping = false;
                }
            },
            end: "+=3000",
            pin: `.${styles.photocard_box}`
        })

        console.log("ScrollTrigger:", trigger);

        const handleWheel = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("Wheel event:", e);
            scrubTo(scrub.vars.totalTime + (e.deltaY * 0.01));
            console.log("scrub :", scrub.vars);
        }

        container.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);

        return (
            () => {
                trigger.kill();
                scrub.kill();
                container.removeEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
            }
        )

        function wrapForward(trigger) {
            iteration++;
            trigger.wrapping = true;
            trigger.scroll(trigger.start + 1);
        }

        function wrapBackward(trigger) {
            iteration--;
            if (iteration < 0) {
                iteration = 9;
                seamlessLoop.totalTime(seamlessLoop.totalTime() + seamlessLoop.duration() * 10);
                scrub.pause();
            }
            trigger.wrapping = true;
            trigger.scroll(trigger.end - 1);
        }

        function scrubTo(totalTime) {
            let progress = (totalTime - seamlessLoop.duration() * iteration) / seamlessLoop.duration();
            if (progress > 1) {
                wrapForward(trigger);
            } else if (progress < 0) {
                wrapBackward(trigger);
            } else {
                trigger.scroll(trigger.start + progress * (trigger.end - trigger.start));
            }
        }

    }, [projectList])


    // useEffect(() => {

    //     // 스크롤 속도 조절
    //     const scrollSpeed = 0.7;

    //     // 마우스 휠 이벤트
    //     const handleWheel = (e) => {
    //         if (scrollContainerRef.current) {
    //             scrollContainerRef.current.scrollLeft += e.deltaY * scrollSpeed;
    //         }
    //     }

    //     // 스크롤 가능 여부 확인
    //     const checkScrollable = () => {
    //         if (scrollContainerRef.current) {
    //             const { scrollWidth, clientWidth, scrollLeft } = scrollContainerRef.current;
    //             setIsScrollableR(scrollWidth > clientWidth && scrollLeft < scrollWidth - 5 - clientWidth);
    //             setIsScrollableL(scrollLeft > 5);
    //         }
    //     };

    //     // 스크롤 중앙 판별
    //     const handleScroll = () => {
    //         const container = scrollContainerRef.current;
    //         if (!container) return;

    //         const cards = container.querySelectorAll(`.${styles.photocard}`);
    //         const containerCenter = container.offsetWidth / 2;
    //         const containerScrollLeft = container.scrollLeft;

    //         cards.forEach( (card) => {
    //             const cardRect = card.getBoundingClientRect();
    //             const cardCenter = cardRect.left + cardRect.width / 2;
    //             const offset = Math.abs(containerCenter - (cardCenter - containerScrollLeft));

    //             const scale = Math.max(0.8, 1 - offset / 500);
    //             const opacity = Math.max(0.5, 1 - offset / 500);

    //             card.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
    //             card.style.opacity = opacity;
    //         })
    //     }

    //     // 스크롤 변화 적용
    //     const container = scrollContainerRef.current;
    //     if (container) {
    //         container.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
    //         container.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    //         checkScrollable(); // 초기 체크
    //         window.addEventListener("resize", checkScrollable); // 창 크기 변경 시 체크
    //         container.addEventListener("scroll", checkScrollable); // 스크롤 시 체크
    //     }

    //     // 이벤트 변경 로직 종료 시 이벤트 핸들 회수
    //     return (() => {
    //         if (container) {
    //             container.removeEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
    //             container.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    //             container.removeEventListener("scroll", checkScrollable);
    //         }
    //         window.removeEventListener("resize", checkScrollable);
    //     })
    // }, [projectList])


    return (

        <div className={[styles.photocard_box,].join(" ")}>
            {/* <div className={[styles.photocard_group, "custom_scrollbar", isScrollableR && styles.gradient_r, isScrollableL && styles.gradient_l].join(" ")} ref={scrollContainerRef}> */}
            <div className={[styles.photocard_group, "custom_scrollbar",].join(" ")} ref={scrollContainerRef}>


                {projectList.map((project, idx) => {
                    return (
                        <Photocard key={["photocard", "map", idx].join("_")} projectData={project} />
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}




chat with chatGPT on 4 days
search with Docs and Example on other's site

help me
